# Does the JVM optimize aliased variables?

Tags: java, variables, optimization, jvm

I'm curious. If I make a few local variables that are used simply as aliases to other variables (that is, a new "alias" variable is simply assigned the value of some other variable and the alias' assignment never changes), does the JVM optimize this by using the original variables directly?

Say, for example, that I'm writing an (immutable) quaternion class (a [quaternion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) is a vector with four values). I write a `multiply()` method that takes another `Quaternion`, multiplies the two, and returns the resulting `Quaternion`. To save on typing and increase readability, I make several aliases before performing the actual computation:

```
public class Quaternion {

    private double[] qValues;

    public Quaternion(double q0, double q1, double q2, double q3) {
        qValues = new double[] {q0, q1, q2, q3};
    }

    // ...snip...

    public Quaternion multiply(Quaternion other) {
        double a1 = qValues[0],
                 b1 = qValues[1],
                 c1 = qValues[2],
                 d1 = qValues[3],

                 a2 = other.qValues[0],
                 b2 = other.qValues[1],
                 c2 = other.qValues[2],
                 d2 = other.qValues[3];

        return new Quaternion(
                    a1*a2 - b1*b2 - c1*c2 - d1*d2,
                    a1*b2 + b1*a2 + c1*d2 - d1*c2,
                    a1*c2 - b1*d2 + c1*a2 + d1*b2,
                    a1*d2 + b1*c2 - c1*b2 + d1*a2
                );
    }

}
```

So, in this case, would the JVM do away with `a1`, `b1`, etc. and simply use `qValues[n]` and `other.qValues[n]` directly?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an alias as you've described it in Java. When you assign a value from one memory location to a new variable, the JVM makes a copy of that value. If it were to create an alias, changing the underlying arrays during the calculation from another thread would alter the result. This does not happen in your example because you specifically told the JVM to make copies of the values first.

If you're worried about performance, don't be. Program correctness trumps all performance concerns. Any program that produces incorrect results faster is worthless. I'm not saying that accessing the arrays directly inside the calculation will necessarily produce incorrect results as I haven't seen the rest of the code, but I am saying that this type of micro-optimization is not worth your effort without first finding a performance problem and next performing timing tests to verify where that problem lies.

Comment: Correct on the "aliases" point, but his code is not thread-safe independently of the use of local copies of the array values or not.

Comment: It really depends on what `...snip...` contains. ;) Given that this question is about variable aliasing and not multithreading, I suspect this wasn't the point of the question.

Comment: Say we have something like `foo(int[] a, int[] b) { a[0..n] = b[5] + 1;}` (pseudo code but should be obvious). Clearly `a` and `b` can refer to the same data in memory, but have two different symbolic names at this point. Wouldn't that be the definition for aliasing?

Comment: Going with what @Voo said, I didn't mean to imply that there was an actual alias mechanism in the language, but rather that the variables acted like aliases. I had figured that perhaps since the usage was obvious to the JVM, that it might optimize it somehow.

Comment: @Voo - `int[] a` means that `a` holds a reference (think pointer in C) to an object--an array of integers. If `b` points to that same object, it means that `b` has a copy of the reference. An alias would mean that changing the reference in `b`--not the underlying object to which it points--would also change the reference in `a`. This is not possible in Java.

Comment: In the question, `qValues` holds a reference to the array while `a1`, `a2`, etc. hold copies of the `double` values from the array.

Comment: @David That seems a rather strict definition. After all the reason for defining aliasing in the first place is because it's important for compiler optimizations. And clearly we run into the same problems with arrays and objects in general there. Wiki also defines it as `a data location in memory can be accessed through different symbolic names` which is true here. I assume I should take my old copy of the dragons book out and look if I find a definition there..

Comment: @Voo - You might find the [Wikipedia entry on references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_\(computer_science\)) interesting. Do you have an example of aliases in other languages that you feel apply to references in Java?

Comment: @David I do know what references, pointers and co are. The point is if we use the definition `a data location in memory can be accessed through different symbolic names` java certainly allows aliasing for all objects. And it just seems like the pragmatic definition, because after all that's exactly what we're interested in when writing an optimizing compiler because it allows further optimizations. How would you define aliasing?

Comment: @Voo - The definition you provided is fine, but this does not describe references in Java. Two variables, `a` and `b` may share the same reference *value* and thus point to the same object, but those symbolic names themselves point to two *separate* memory locations that hold the references.

Comment: @David References in java are basically identical to pointers to const structs in C. I mean with `int[] a` a does point to the address of the array and not to the position where it is stored (that'd be a rather useless additional indirection). So if I start gdb and debug such code, the values of both a and b will be identical.

Comment: @Voo - Yes, the *values* of `a` and `b` will be identical, but where are those values stored? A: In separate memory addresses. Changing one does not change the other and thus they are not aliases for each other. The compiler cannot optimize them to be a single variable.

Comment: @David The location of a and b? Well almost anything, including not at all because the compiler keeps them in registers (also yes if the compiler could prove that a and b always pointed to the same location he could store them in one spot, though hardly a useful property). Also the definition says `same location in memory that can be *accessed* through different symbolic names` and that is possible (because clearly when we access `a` we don't access the maybe non existent location where it is itself stored, but what it points to).

Comment: Seems to me that's the important property we have to prove for certain optimizations, not whether a and b are stored in the same location or not

Comment: Unless the two variables are local, it's possible that they could be changed by another thread as is the case with the code in the question. Either way, I don't consider compiler optimizations such as you describe to equate to the definition of aliases you quote. We'll just have to agree to disagree. :)

Answer (score 1):

The javac compiler won't do it. Disassembling a simple piece of code like this:

```
    int a = 1;
    int b = a;
    System.out.println("" + (a - b));
```

Shows:

```
   0: iconst_1      
   1: istore_1      
   2: iload_1       
   3: istore_2
   ...
```

But this is what the interpreter will be executing (and even the interpreter sometimes can do some basic optimization). The JIT compiler will handle these kinds of optimizations and many others; in the case of you method, it's even small enough to be inlined, so you don't even get the method call overhead once the JIT kicks in.

(e.g., in my example, the JIT can very easily do constant propagation and just do away with the variables and the calculation, just calling using `"" + 0` as the argument to the println() method.)

But, at the end, just follow what JIT hackers always say: write your code to be maintainable. Don't worry about what the JIT will or will not do.

(Note: David is correct about variables not being "aliases", but copies of the original values.)

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, there no concept of aliasing variables in Java, and the value of a variable is stored per variable declared.

Using local variables to store values of an array for future calculations is a better idea as it makes code more readable, and eliminates extra reads from an array.

That being said, creating local variables does increase the size of the allocated java stack frame in the thread for the method. This would not be an issue in this specific question, but greater number of local variables would increase the stack size required for execution. This would be especially relevant if recursion is involved.

Answer (score -1):

Your program should work but the answer to your questions is no. JVM will not treat `a1` as an alias of `qValues[0]`, instead it copy the value of the latter to the former.

Check this good referenece: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html

Comment: Your cited reference has nothing to do with the question. -1.

Comment: Please elaborate your statement. What's your understanding to the question?

Comment: The question is about aliases. The reference is about parameter passing.

Comment: Well, just as all answers pointed out, alias concept does not exist in Java. The reason it's put in the question by Mr. derefed is because he didn't quite understand the parameter passing mechanism in Java by that time. And that's why I put the reference over there. I don't see why it's nothing to do with the question and why my answer got a vote down

Comment: Exactly. There is no alis concept in Java. So there are no citations that describe it. So *any* citation is going to be irrelevant. He is talking throughout about local variables. He hasn't said a word about parameter passing; that is your own, irrelevant, contribution.

Comment: I think understanding the mechanism of parameter passing does help to understand the question been asked. as long as the people see that Java always passing variables by value, he could very well understand assign an array item to another variable by value not reference (i.e. alias). The 2 things a not absolutely irrelevant. Let's say in C++ you can pass a reference of a parameter to a function by `func(int & a)`, and you use the same pattern to pass reference to a local variable: `int & a = i`. What I want to say is these two things are in fact correlated, instead of irrelevant.

Comment: About the citation, it's not about talking about a faked concept alias in Java, it's provided as a reference to help people to understand the language.

Comment: You asked why the downvote. I have told you. I don't agree with your justification and I'm not interested in debating it endlessly.